# From eclipse to phone I get INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android, testing

I am working on a game in eclipse.  I connect my android phone to test the application. Upon pressing "RUN" in eclipse, the game will begin to be uploaded to my device.  However, it onl makes it half way then the console in eclipse gives me this error:   INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE.  I checked my internal storage and I have 30mb left.  My game is 3.20mb.  I should have plenty of room. shouldn't I?  Is this just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when I had a copy of my application that was signed with a release key already on the device. So here is what I recommend...

1. Do a clean build of your project
2. Remove your application from the phone via the application manager on the phone
3. Try to run again

Something else that might be worth looking into is where the app is set to be installed. If it's the SD Card, make sure the virtual SD card does have the needed room.

Comment: i have tried the solution that you have given and i am encountering the same problem.. the solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and i solved it as per the first answer that i have received.... check it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044520/android-app-not-installling-on-device)