# Android app not installing on device?

Tags: android

```
INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
```

The above is the error that my phone gives when i try and install the application. The .apk file of my app is 1.26 MB.

The phone memory free on my device is 16MB. Now when i try and install the app, why is my device giving the above error?

Also I am using Android 2.2 on my app, if i use `android:preferenceLocation="external"` it gives me INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE error. So I removed the above command from the manifest file and then tried. This resulted in the error i have mentioned above regarding insufficient storage.

What do I need to do regarding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether your device has a SD card or not. If it has then check whether it is mounted on your PC/mac or not. If it is mounted then unmount the sd card from the system and try re installing the app again.

Comment: but i am installing the app on the phone memory.

Comment: also i have a mac. my device also has an sd card. How do i unmount the sdcard without ejecting my device?

Comment: drag the notification bar, click on "turn off USB storage"

Comment: nopes, it started working. Just had to clean my project and try again.. it is a real problem with eclipse, the way you have to keep on cleaning the project...

Comment: also why did i have to unmount the sdcard. My device had enough phone memory, why was OS not installing the app inside the phone memory?

Comment: because you have mentioned preferred location as "external"

Comment: i said i removed it. you misunderstood my question.

Comment: i again had the same problem.. and i did what i did before but it is not going. i cleaned the project several times but to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

Just check your phone connection type. It should not be SD Card access mode. It must be "Portal and Tools" (I don't know exactly if it's a particular name for my Motorola Droid). Just check the notification area. It works perfectly!